# Xcode 4.5 quit unexpectedly

Tags: iphone, xcode

quit and restart, quit and restart, ..., for many times.
I got a log shown below:

```
Process:         Xcode [1156]
Path:            /Users/USER/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         4.5 (1839)
Build Info:      IDEApplication-1839000000000000~3
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [150]
User ID:         502

Date/Time:       2012-09-25 21:02:15.533 +0800
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8 (12A269)
Report Version:  10

Interval Since Last Report:          1620650 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           66
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  209706 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   62
Anonymous UUID:                      410E9490-9BA7-4C02-8213-2D855F72E50B

Crashed Thread:  1  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 4G182
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEFoundation/IDEFoundation-1877/Framework/Classes/Model/SourceControl/IDESourceControlWorkspaceMonitor.m:1054
Details:  Attempted to add repository (IDESourceControlRepository) Name:xuexi@192.168.0,     Type:Subversion,
 Location:svn://xuexi@192.168.0.109 when (IDESourceControlRepository)   Name:xuexi@192.168.0, 
Type:Subversion, 
Location:svn://xuexi@192.168.0.109 already existed.
Object:   <IDESourceControlWorkspaceMonitor: 0x408e59140>
Method:   -_findWorkingTreesForFilePath:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x40937d480>{name = (null), num = 11}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0  0x00000001075167ef -[IDEAssertionHandler   handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x00000001067e02a5 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x0000000107073cfd __block_global_5 (in IDEFoundation)
  3  0x00007fff93f9acac -[NSBlockOperation main] (in Foundation)
  4  0x00007fff93f70bb6 -[__NSOperationInternal start] (in Foundation)
  5  0x00007fff93f783d1 __block_global_6 (in Foundation)
  6  0x00007fff8c07bf3d _dispatch_call_block_and_release (in libdispatch.dylib)
  7  0x00007fff8c0780fa _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
  8  0x00007fff8c07923e _dispatch_worker_thread2 (in libdispatch.dylib)
  9  0x00007fff942f6ceb _pthread_wqthread (in libsystem_c.dylib)
 10  0x00007fff942e11b1 start_wqthread (in libsystem_c.dylib)

objc[1156]: garbage collection is ON
abort() called
```

really need help!

Comment: ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEFoundation/IDEFoundation-1877/Framework/Classes/Model/SourceControl/IDESourceControlWorkspaceMonitor.m:1054  *************  see here? It seems my SVN crashed xCode.

Comment: try by deleting all derived data projects, and start Xcode again..  here is the path for derived data /Users/******/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

Comment: I tried, and still failed to restart.

Comment: I don't understand why this answer is closed, since it describes a programming related question. There are several other questions like this on SO and the didn't got closed. Anyway. The comment here provided instant help!

Comment: Renaming the IDESubversion.ideplugin file that is inside XCode.app to IDESubversion-DISABLED.ideplugin worked for me

Comment: Please, reopen this question!!  It also happen to me when I try to open a directory that I had previosly copy from a working project

Comment: @EvaMadrazo I totally agree with you.

Comment: Xcode found an internal inconsistency and decided to abort before making things worst. This is not answerable. It would be foolish to try to reverse engineer it and fix it when next version of Xcode is always near. If you mix code from different SVN projects, avoid copying the hidden .svn subdirectory. If this keeps happening, disable SVN and use a different client until Apple releases another Xcode.

Comment: @Jano Was this question closed by you?

Comment: A question can be closed by a moderator or by the votes of 5 users with at least 3,000 rep. In this case I'm one of those users, the others are listed below.

Comment: @Jano Can I ask you to reopen this question? Or give a proper reason to close it. I do respect you for your contribution to the StackOverflow, but I also want justice.

Comment: Sorry, as I explained above, I believe the problem is inside Xcode and only Apple can fix it.

Comment: @Jano You assumed what the answer was and closed the question based on your assumption. But (at least in my case) your assumption was incorrect. I had exactly the problem described in this question and I don't use SVN or anything related. In my case it was a StoreKit issue - specifically, when you call SKProductsRequest and you're on the iOS6 simulator you get "lsd quit unexpectedly". You can avoid that by using #if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR but of course then don't expect to do in-app purchases.

Comment: See my previous comments. It's irrelevant if the cause was the SVN module or something else. The crash clearly indicates a fault in Apple's code. The way to fix that is filing a radar bug with Apple, not reverse engineering Xcode. Fixing Xcode was flagged offtopic (by 5 users). If you have enough reputation vote to reopen or flag for moderator attention, but it would be wrong to do so.

Comment: @Jano Waiting for Apple to fix the issue is not an option, especially when, months later, the crash is still occurring for many people. We have work to do, we have to find a workaround. Preferably something easier than erasing my hard drive and re-installing everything without restoring from a backup...

Comment: I was able to solve the crash by going into File -> Source Control -> Repositories and deleting the ones matching the error log (it was listed twice). Not sure how it happened, the project was working earlier this morning and I erased it, created a fresh checkout from a revision months old, and it still crashed. But deleting the repo from the repositories list fixed the crash.