# Objective-C property, expose only superclass

Tags: objective-c, foundation

I am declaring a property in my class in header file;

```
@property (readonly) NSArray *pages
```

That's how I want it to be exposed publicly. Internally though, I am going to allocating it as NSMutableArray so I can add/remove stuff from it. But to do that, I will have to type cast every time. Is there a better way to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a solution for this. You have to cast every time, or use different properties. Here is a sample for the second approach:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSArray *pages;
-(void)addObject:(id)obj;
@end

@interface MyClass()
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSMutableArray *mPages;
@end

@implementation MyClass
-(id) init {
    self = [super init]
    if (self){
        _mPages = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return self;
}
-(NSArray*)pages {
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:self.mPages];
}
-(void)addObject:(id)obj {
    [self.mPages addObject:obj];
}
@end


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        MyClass *m = [MyClass new];
        [m addObject:@"x"];     // the collection is mutable
        NSLog(@"%@",[m pages]); // but only accessible as an immutable copy
    }
}
```

This will be expensive if you access the collection frequently, and may be out of sync with the internal mutable collection (which may be mutated while you iterate on the copy).

Copying can be avoided returning the internal mutable instance (NSMutableArray) disguised as an immutable class (NSArray), but that incurs the following risks:

- The client could cast to mutable and change it.
- The internal copy could be mutated. This will crash the application if you are iterating, or may cause an index out of range exception.

---

Note that the following idiom doesn't solve the problem:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSArray *pages;
@end

@interface MyClass()
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSMutableArray *pages;
@end
```

This lets you set the variable, but not use it as a different class than the one declared in the interface. In other words, it forces you to cast on every use:

```
[(NSMutableArray*)pages addObject:@"x"];
```

Comment: hmm...doesn't strong imply readwrite with ownership ? This works, I am just wondering why. (saying strong, readonly doesn't make any sense)

Comment: No, it only implies ownership for memory management purposes (you only retain strongly what you own). You can own a read only variable.

Comment: Is the declared pages and the redeclared pages the same one?

Comment: Yes, it is the same mutable instance.

Comment: But I can't call the `addObject:` for the pages in the implementation? Have you tried this?

Comment: Initialize with a mutable instance in your constructor and try [(NSMutableArray*)self.pages addObject:obj];

Comment: Jano, that was the original problem :( - 'But to do that, I will have to type cast every time.'

Comment: No way out of that I'm afraid. What the property readwrite does is letting you set the variable pages. You could add a property with a different name in the interface and override the getter to return a [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableArray]

Comment: @Jano I have to be here to tell you that you shouldn't close a question like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583725/xcode-4-5-quit-unexpectedly. Please review it again and seriously. I think my question is just the third one here:software tools commonly used by programmers  http://stackoverflow.com/faq  . Expect your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is really bad. If you insist on exposing a mutable array with dynamic content, then modify your getter to return an immutable copy, otherwise you are going to get weird side effects and exceptions for mutations during fast enumeration.

Comment: I don't insist on exposing a mutable array. I want to expose a non-mutable array. If i expose a non-mutable array, it can't be mutated externally (if someone else type casts to mutable, then that's their problem). Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @OxSina But it can be mutated internally while someone is iterating on what they think is an inmutable array.